# jQuery hide - how to know if element has started to hide but still visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

I have form where are inputs. Answers and visibility of the inputs may affect visibility of other inputs which are located below it.

I have javascript function which is called when value of some of the inputs have changed. The function is going through every input and checking it’s visibility and answer. Based on that information it may hide or show some other inputs. One loop is enough, because visibility of the element can’t affect visibility of previous elements.

```
$(".test_this").each(function() {
    var id_number = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];
    var tested_id = parseInt(id_number) + 1;
    if ($(this).find("input:checked").val() != 1 || $(this).is(":hidden")) {
        if ($("#element_"+tested_id).is(":visible")) {
            $("#element_"+tested_id).hide();
        }
    }
    else {
        if ($("#element_"+tested_id).is(":hidden")) {
            $("#element_"+tested_id).show(500);   
        }                     
    }                  
});
```

My code is working well, but I would like to add duration to hide-function, but then my visibility check fails. Is it possible to know if some element has started to hide but is still visible?

I don’t want to use callback function, because it is executed after the delay. Second, I don’t want to change values of hidden inputs. One solution is to add some extra class which existence would be possible to check, but is there some better way to do this?

My code in Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nmUPj/3/

For the further information, my actual code is lot more complicated and getting information about form from MySQL and generating form and javascript code with PHP.

Comment: If `hide()` is used without a duration, it's not asynchronous, and there is no "started to hide", it's hidden or it's not. If it's animated, it will be ... wait for it ... animated -> `if ($(element).is(':animated')) { ... }`. What you're probably looking for is to just add a class to the elements, and then check for that class, as then it would'nt matter if it was animated or not.

Comment: @adeneo Thank you for your comment. Maybe adding new class is the best choice is my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the element is still animating by:

```
$("#element_"+tested_id).is(":animated")
```

Alternatively, you can give a callback function to your show(),

```
$("#element_"+tested_id).show(5000, function(){
    alert('animation completed');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that, but still it's not solving my problem, because then I don't know is it animated because of hide or show.